# Problems to make a text scroll infinitely

Tags: html, css, flexbox

good morning, I am having complications to make a text scroll infinitely from right to left. The problem is that after a while it restarts.
I thought that adding more labels with the same text would solve it but no. I also get the bottom bar on the page to scroll the content and I shouldn't.
This is the code:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.adbar-container {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  animation: slide-left 20s linear infinite;
}

.adbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.adbar > p {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
  }
}
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Header</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="adbar-container">
      <section class="adbar">
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20rem;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scroll-element {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.scroll-element p {
  width: 15%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.primary {
  animation: primary 20s linear infinite;
}

.secondary {
  animation: secondary 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes primary {
  from {
    left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

@keyframes secondary {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Header</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scroll-parent">
      <section class="scroll-element primary">
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
      </section>

      <section class="scroll-element secondary">
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
        <p>OVERSIZE CLUB CREATED FOR THE NEW ERA</p>
        <p>ENVÍOS A TODA LA ARGENTINA</p>
        <p>[ENVIO GRATIS] +2 PRENDAS</p>
      </section>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, yes, thank you, I'm just having a little trouble understanding what you did.